# SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services Control

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Is the Sql Server 2008 control available for download?  Does it yet support the 2008 RDL schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReportViewer control, http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef&DisplayLang=en , supports 2005 RDL using LocalMode (ReportViewer.LocalReport) and 2008 from a Server (ReportViewer.ServerReport).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the ReportViewer control, it is [available](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef&DisplayLang=en).

However you need Windows XP, Windows Vista or Windows Server 2003 to install it. It is also written that .NET 3.5 is required, but I'm not sure about this one. I managed to install it with .NET 2.0 on an XP.

Answer (score 0):

The ReportViewer control should work just fine with SQL Server 2008.